# Function FullSimplify unable to simplify relatively simple algebraic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I want to simplify with *Mathematica 11* the following algebraic expression under the assumptions $x<0$ and $y>0$:

```
A= (-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y])/Sqrt[2 x^2 + y - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + y]]
```

A short calculation yields `A = 1`. But *Mathematica* seems not able to obtain that result when the following expression is evaluated:

```
FullSimplify[A,Assumptions->x<0&&y>0]
```

**Is it possible to help Mathematica to solve this?**

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What is that *"short calculation "* that yields `A = 1`?

Comment: You can complete the square in the denominator, explicitly: 2x^2 + y - 2 x Sqrt[x^2+y] = (-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y])^2

Comment: Strange indeed.  `Simplify[A == 1, ...]` and `Simplify[A^2, ...]` both work.  You could use the latter to figure out that the result must be either 1 or -1, and the former to show that it is always 1.

Comment: Even this works: `Reduce[A == z, {x, y}, Reals]`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. My problem is that A is part of a much bigger expression and I rely on FullSimplify to correctly simplify it. And I want to avoid using replacement rules, which wouldn't be elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to add [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) to the list of [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunction) rules. For example:

```
oneReduce[x_] := If[TrueQ @ !Reduce[{x != 1, $Assumptions}], 1, x]
```

If [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) can determine that `x != 1` is definitely [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) based on [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions), then it transforms `x` to `1`. Let's see this in action:

```
Assuming[x<0 && y>0, Simplify[A, TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, oneReduce}]]
```

> 1

Another useful transformation function is:

```
zeroReduce[x_] := If[TrueQ @ !Reduce[{x != 0, $Assumptions}], 0, x]
```

Perhaps this approach will work with more complicated expressions.

Comment: That's definitely an elegant and useful solution. In my case computationally too expensive though.